# Run SH file, open dialog for sudo

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm writing a .sh file which should open monodevelop in root mode. I don't want a terminal to be used for it since it has to stay open.

Now, what I currently got:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo monodevelop
```

Now I need to run it in a terminal, but I want my script to bring up a dialog when clicked on Run (not Run in terminal) so I can enter my password for sudo, so it will run monodevelop as root afterwards.

Is there any way I can get this done?

Comment: Use `gksu` instead of sudo (you might need to install `gksu`). Must be a dupe of something.

Comment: Glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob Vlijm said:

It's simply done by using gksu except for sudo:

```
#!/bin/bash
gksu monodevelop
```